# How can I make a link open in a new window using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make a set of links open in a new window - the good thing is they all have the same css style - what do i need to do in css to get these links opened in new window?

Comment: CSS is about _presentation_; you can't alter a link's _behavior_ with it.

Answer (score 4):

As per the comments:

> *and how can i specify window size? i want it a little smaller than the original page. also, can i make all links in the page, open in the SAME new window, of a smaller size?*

You can't use CSS or HTML to do this. You need to use JavaScript's [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open). You can get all links by [`element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) on `a` and you can determine the link's `class` attribute by [`element.className`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM:element.className):

```
window.onload = function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = links[i];
        if (link.className == 'someClass') {
            link.onclick = function() {
                window.open(this.href, 'chooseYourName', 'width=600,height=400');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Or if you're already using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), you can use `$('a.someClass')` to select all links which has the specified class `someClass`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.someClass').click(function() {
        window.open(this.href, 'chooseYourName', 'width=600,height=400');
        return false;
    });
});
```

The window's name as specified in `chooseYourName` will take care that all links are (re)opened in the same window. You also see that you can specify the width and height over there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use CSS to do this. You need to use `<a target="_blank"></a>`.

**Edit:** Javascript's [window.open](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) command.

Comment: and how can i specify window size? i want it a little smaller than the original page. also, can i make all links in the page, open in the SAME new window, of a smaller size?

Comment: You can use a JavaScript on-click event for basic window resizing. Research the window.open command.

Comment: and, how do i open all links in the SAME new window?

Comment: Use the same name in the event, it will use the window with that name instead of creating another new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with CSS. You should do this with a small script such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function newwindow()
{
    var load = window.open('http://www.domain.com');
}
</Script>
```